# Error on a line on third iteration of cycling through fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, countdowntimer

I have made an android application where in I first login and then show a main activity which has a navigation drawer. The navigation drawer has Home and Profile. The home shows a countdown timer while the profile retrieves the information from database and shows it. 
The first time main.class comes it goes to Home and shows the countdown. Then I move to profile. The profile page shows correctly.
Now here it becomes difficult to understand for me. then i go to home (it shows correctly) then profile and then home (there is an error now)

I am not able to figure out why is there an error. Kindly help. I am new to android programming.

MenuFragment.java is the one that shows the countdown.
The error is in line

```
TextView mTextField = (TextView)getActivity().findViewbById(R.id.welcome);
```

of MenuFragment.java in third iteration.

Here is the main.class

```
public class Main extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private TextView mTextField;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mMenuTitles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mMenuTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);






    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
     // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action buttons
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_websearch:
        // create intent to perform web search for this planet
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
        // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {

        selectItem(position);
    }
}
private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments

    if (position == 1)
    {
        Fragment fragment = new FragmentProfile();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putInt(FragmentProfile.ARG_MENU_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "current_fragment").commit();
    }
    else
    {

    Fragment fragment = new MenuFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(MenuFragment.ARG_MENU_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer



    //timer.cancel();

    }
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mMenuTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}



@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}



@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
 */





}
```

Here is MenuFragment.java

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String ARG_MENU_NUMBER = "menu_number";
public static boolean ifpause = false;
public static boolean flag = false;

public MenuFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_MENU_NUMBER);
    View rootView;


            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);




    String menu = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array)[i];
    TextView mTextField = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.welcome);
    mTextField.setText("00:00:10");
    final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(10000,1000); 
    timer.start();




    System.out.println(i);
    getActivity().setTitle(menu);
    return rootView;
}

public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    ifpause = true;
}   
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ifpause=false;
    flag=true;

}

public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer { 
    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
    { 
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }
    public TextView mTextField = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.welcome);
    @Override 
    public void onFinish() 
    { 

        } 
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
    { 

        long millis = millisUntilFinished; 
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), 
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), 
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))); 

        if(!ifpause)
        {
            TextView mTextField = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.welcome);
            mTextField.setText(hms); 

        }


    }
}



}
```

Logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime(4456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(4456): Process: com.example.test, PID: 4456
E/AndroidRuntime(4456): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(4456): at      com.example.test.MenuFragment$CounterClass.onTick(MenuFragment.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime(4456): at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:124)
E/AndroidRuntime(4456): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(4456): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(4456): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime(4456): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(4456): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(4456): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(4456): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime(4456): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you've got a race condition here.

The fragment has probably been detached from its parent Activity.   You'll need to cancel the timer when you are done with it.  Probably in onDestroyView.

Make a private member variable to hold onto your timer.  Use that when you initialize it in your onCreateView method.  Then, make use of it in your overridden onDestroyView method like so:

```
private CounterClass timer;

@Override
public void onDestroyView()
{
    super.onDestroyView();

    if (timer != null)
    {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}
```

In addition, you might want to guard against your fragment not being attached to an Activity in your onTick method by checking for getActivity() == null and returning early in that case.

For more information on the Fragment lifecycle, please look here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try to do it today. There is another problem. When I am running it in debug mode with several breakpoints in MenuFragment.java, the code seems to work correctly. Any idea of why that kind of thing happens? Could you please explain or if possible, could you give some reference link to study this kind of behaviour?

Comment: I think all you would have to do is navigate to and then away from this fragment to get the crash.

Comment: Yes, I am doing that. I am going from home to profile and then to home, several times but not getting the crash in debug mode. It just works. But when I remove the breakpoints and then run in debug mode and switch fragment repeatedly, I get a crash. I think this is related to the time lag created while pressing the "run" button to pass the breakpoint which is preventing the crash.